How do I go on with finding the Inverse Laplace of this function?
I was finding the time-dependent equation for a process $f(t)$ by using the Laplace transform. I have simplified the equation to this form:
$$
F(s)=\frac{-\frac{1}{s} \cdot \sinh(r\sqrt{s})}{\sinh({\sqrt{s})} + \sqrt{s} \cdot \cosh({r\sqrt{s})}}
$$
$F(s)$ is independent of $r$. I have tried multiple paths and simplifications from this point, all ending up in a format that looks like it has a standard inverse Laplace, but one or the other term is in excess. For example, I tried taking the reciprocal and taking the exponential equivalent of the hyperbolic functions and ended up with a format as follows:
$$
\frac{1}{F(s)}=\frac{e^r}{(1-e^{-2\sqrt{s}})^{r-1}} - \left( \frac{1-e^{-r\sqrt{s}}}{1+e^{-r\sqrt{s}}} \cdot s\sqrt{s} \right)
$$
I know for a fact that when the equation is broken down, each of the parts is close-to or is a standard Laplace inverse function.
Am I heading in the right direction? If so, how do I go on from here?
If not, what is the right way?
Thanks!

$F(s,r)=\frac{-\frac{1}{s} \cdot \sinh(r\sqrt{s})}{\sinh({\sqrt{s})} + \sqrt{s} \cdot \cosh({r\sqrt{s})}}$ depends on $r$. Taking $r=0$ or $r\to\infty$ and keeping $s>0$
$$F(s,r=0)=0\neq F(s,r\to \infty)=-s^{-3/2}$$

I tried to invert $F(s,r)$ numerically, see Jupyter notebook MSE_Q4973138
